# PHP preg_match parser - How get uppercase letters

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I have code that parse copypasted mediainfo text and create the array, but I have a problem because in this code `$line` needs to be a lower case, otherwise it's not print anything.

How I can make this working with uppercase letters?

If I change this to `strtoupper` code not working anymore.

`$line = trim(strtolower($line));`

If I wanna parse filename it's always lowercase.

**Example:**

Original:

**My.Home.Video.S01.E01.mp4**

After parse:

**my.home.video.s01.e01.mp4**

```
class Parser {

// Mediainfo 
private $regex_section = "/^(?:(?:general|video|audio|text|menu)(?:\s\#\d+?)*)$/i";

public function parse($string)
{
    $string = trim($string);
    $lines = preg_split("/\r\n|\n|\r/", $string);

    $output = [];
    foreach ($lines as $line) {
        $line = trim(strtolower($line));
        if (preg_match($this->regex_section, $line)) {
            $section = $line;
            $output[$section] = [];
        }
        if (isset($section)) {
            $output[$section][] = $line;
        } else {
            $output['general'][] = $line;
        }
    }
```

EDIT:

Whole code: https://pastebin.com/MkxSYk1W

If I remove `strtolower` from this line  `$line = trim(strtolower($line));`

I got this when I print output. No values.

`Array ( [general] => [video] => [audio] => [text] => )`

Comment: It does not have to be lowercase, look [here](https://3v4l.org/F1dMa).

Comment: Hi and thanks for the response. I edited a first post and added full code and what I got if I remove strtolower and print output.

Comment: @Wiktor your commented answer shows a "video" filename stored in the "general" subarray.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly you would like to group the filenames by section.

```
$filenames = [
    'My.Home.Video.S01.E01.mp4',
    'my.home.video.s01.e02.mp4',
    'My.Home.Audio.S01.E01.mp4'
];

// match specific strings between dots, capture as "section"
$pattern = '(\\.(?<section>general|video|audio|text|menu)\\.)i';

$output = [];
foreach ($filenames as $filename) {
    // default section
    $section = 'general';
    if (preg_match($pattern, $filename, $match)) {
        // lowercase captured section
        $section = strtolower($match['section'] ?? 'general');
    }
    if (isset($output[$section])) {
        // add to existing group
        $output[$section][] = $filename;
    } else {
        // add new group
        $output[$section] = [$filename];
    }
    
}

var_dump($output);
```

Output:

```
array(2) {
  ["video"]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(25) "My.Home.Video.S01.E01.mp4"
    [1]=>
    string(25) "my.home.video.s01.e02.mp4"
  }
  ["audio"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(25) "My.Home.Audio.S01.E01.mp4"
  }
}
```

Comment: I am always mystified when I post a more refined answer, then another answer get UV'ed (this hapens too often around my answers).  I must have some "special fans", but what satisfaction can they be deriving from steering researchers away from the better answer just to snub me?  I'll never understand.

Answer (score 0):

Grouping your files can be much more direct / simple.

Look for file "categories" that are between dots in the filename, then if found use the lowercased matched category word as the first level key in the output array.  If no whitelisted  category word is found, then it gets pushed into the general subarray.

No subarray instantiations are necessary here.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/g5gjs))

```
$filenames = [
    'My.Home.Video.S01.E01.mp4',
    'my.home.video.s01.e02.mp4',
    'My.Home.Audio.S01.E01.mp4'
];

$output = [];
foreach ($filenames as $filename) {
    $section = preg_match(
        '~\.(video|audio|text|menu)\.~i',
        $filename,
        $match
    )
    ? strtolower($match[1])
    : 'general';

    $output[$section][] = $filename;
}

var_export($output);
```

Output:

```
array (
  'video' => 
  array (
    0 => 'My.Home.Video.S01.E01.mp4',
    1 => 'my.home.video.s01.e02.mp4',
  ),
  'audio' => 
  array (
    0 => 'My.Home.Audio.S01.E01.mp4',
  ),
)
```

Pro Tip: Instead of `\r\n|\n|\r`, use `\R`.